# Looking for ideas on the properties of a simple matrix

Tags: matrices, polynomials

I am interested in investigating the "theory" of this simple matrix sequence
which I ran across in my studies.

$$A_n(x)=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &x \\
-x& 1
\end{pmatrix}^n$$

E.g. $\det(A_1(x))=1+x^2$ and maybe it is not accidental that this expression
occurs so often in expressions ( e.g. differentiation of $\tan$ ).

Maybe the $n$-degree (?) polynomials generated in the matrix elements
of the $n$-th power matrix
might be interesting - at least the ones in the 2nd column are well-known.

1. does this simple matrix appear elsewhere in math ( physics, chemistry,... ) ?
2. what maybe interesting properties of the sequence ?

Comment: Hint: look for the correspondence between complex numbers and certain $2\times2$ real matrices, namely $a+bi\mapsto\binom{a\ \ -b}{\!b\ \ \ \ a}$.

Comment: Another way of seeing the same thing that Matematicos is suggesting is to diagonalize $A$.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas Do you know a source math textbook where this interesting coresspondance is dealt with ?

Comment: @WolfgangTintemann See this Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Matrix_representation_of_complex_numbers).

Comment: Thanks. By using the correspondence e.g. if I calculated right I get a funny property

Comment: Thanks. By using the correspondence e.g. if I calculated right I get a funny property as $$\sum_{\nu=0}^{\infty}\frac{A_\nu(x)}{\nu !}=e\begin{pmatrix}
cos(x) &sin(x) \\
-sin(x)& cos(x)
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Yes, you just computed exp(1+ix)=exp(1)*(cos(x)+i*sin(x)) in matrix form.